# Android Date Picker selected Day Color

Tags: android, date, colors, datepicker, picker

How do i change the color of the selected day and circle in a Date Picker?
I have tried several properties that are listed on the documentation, however i have had no success.

[This is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNCjw.png)

I made a custom style for my Date Picker.

```html
<style name="datePickerTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
</style>
```

I just cant find the correct property to change the colors that i want.